# Azure Logic Apps: Azure AD Refresh Token Module

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-logic-apps, refresh-token

I'm trying to refresh tokens of an user with the following logic app work flow.
[image: Refresh Tokens]

However, I result in this error.

```
 "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
 "message": "Access to invalidate refresh tokens operation is denied.",
```

A similar but not exact stackoverflow question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76424848/azure-app-registration-not-giving-new-refresh-token-or-scope-because-of-permissi). I'm currenting using a service account on this module - what exact permissions are needed? or is there a different way to approach this if my goal is to refresh the users tokens?

Comment: can you share your complete flow diagram

Comment: @Ikhtesam Afrin This is the complete workflow. A Sentinel Incident occurs and using the user in the incident it refreshes their session token. I'm trying to understand what I need to do to prevent that error. What specific permissions/roles do i need to give to the service account for this module to work.

Comment: gave myself "User Administrator" mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/delegate-by-task). Now i get an error that says:

    "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
    "message": "Access token has expired or is not yet valid.".

i may just have to wait?

Comment: You can wait or add a new connection and try to re-add the actions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you call `Azure AD refresh token` action in logic app, it internally invoke below URL

[image]

In order to perform this action, you need to have `User.ReadWrite.All, Directory.ReadWrite.All` permissions as stated in this [ms docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-revokesigninsessions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

Make sure, you are using the correct user id or Principal Name.

I am able to get the successful response as below-

[image]

For token expiration, refer [this](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/active-directory/develop/refresh-tokens.md).